# How to get the credit achievements?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I got the 100,000 credits achievement. Decided to save up to 1M to get both 500k and 1M. I woke up, opened the app, was past 500k but didn't get the achievement. Thinking maybe I should be connected to Game Center when I actually go past 500k, I purchased a level to go below 500k, and timed a big spender so I would get over 500k when the game was open and I was connected to Game Center. I still didn't get the achievement :(

Anyone else with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem for the 100k achievement. It didn't work the first time, but I waited a couple of hours while over 100k and it finally worked.

Comment: That's exactly what happened to me later. I guess it's a common issue. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 2):

I received the achievements immediately after patching up to 1.1.2.